# Run multiple iterations of one Airflow Operator

Tags: parallel-processing, operators, airflow

I am building a system that is supposed to list files on a remote SFTP server and then download the files locally. I want this to run in parallel such that I can initiate one job for each file to be downloaded, or an upper of say 10 simultaneous downloads.

I am new to Airflow and still not fully understanding everything. I assume there should be a solution to do this but I just can't figure it out.

This is the code, currently I download all files in one Operator, but as far as I know, it is not using multiple workers.

```
def transfer_files():
    for i in range(1, 11): 
        sftp.get(REMOTE_PATH + 'test_{}.csv'.format(i), LOCAL_PATH + 'test_{}.csv'.format(i))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you are using PythonOperator, You can start multiple PythonOperators, it would looks something like this:

```
def get_my_file(i):
    sftp.get(REMOTE_PATH + 'test_{}.csv'.format(i), LOCAL_PATH + 'test_{}.csv'.format(i))

def transfer_files():
    for i in range(1, 11):
        task = PythonOperator(
            task_id='test_{}.csv'.format(i),
            python_callable=get_my_file,
            op_args=[i],
            dag=dag)
```

Comment: This does not appear to work. I tried this for the connection but I see no sign of the file in the REMOTE_PATH. Should this method create an entry in the dag? Because I see no sign of this task_id. 
I tried the same approach for creating some test files and the task is successful but there are no files in the destination folder. It seems to me that it just doesn't run at all

Comment: Did you call transfer_files function at the end?

Comment: I had not correctly assigned the dependencies for the Operators. It works great now!